# creating pagination with mysql stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pagination

M trying to create pagination with stored procedure,

when I try to pass 1 as param it get record 0 to 14.
and when I pass 2 as param it gives 0-30,
I want 15-30 when I pass 2 as param

```
create PROCEDURE abc(pageno INT)
BEGIN  
DECLARE page_no int;
DECLARE rstarts int;
DECLARE rends int; 
DECLARE userPage int;

set @userPage = pageno;

PREPARE STMT FROM 
" SELECT * FROM primaryinfo LIMIT ?,? "; 
SET @START =(@userPage - 1) * 15; 
SET @LIMIT = @userPage * 15; 
EXECUTE STMT USING @START, @LIMIT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
END
```

or is there any other solution to do it effectively..
Thank you in advance

Comment: Try debugging `@start` to see what it holds when you pass 2

Comment: phpmyadmin has no feature to debug it...:-(

Comment: By debugging I mean to see what it holds

Comment: i tried debugging with some tool... START holds the correct value 15 and LIMIT holds 30... but still the result returned is 30 rows....

Comment: I guess it dosen't  support "limit 10,20". it just take it as limit 0,20..i tried it by hardcode way  also..

Answer (score 2):

pagination without statements:

```
create PROCEDURE test(
  IN first_rec integer,
  IN rec_count integer
)
BEGIN
  -- return --
  SET @rownum=0;
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    user.*, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rn FROM user
  ) t WHERE rn>=first_rec and rn<first_rec+rec_count;
END;;
```